# Is there any difference between the following commands from std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, insert, unordered-map

For inserting a key-value pair into an unordered map, e.g., `std::unordered_pair<int,int> map1`, can we do it in any of these two ways:

```
map1[2]=5;
map1.insert({2,5});
```

Is there any difference between using `std_unordered_insert` or `operator[]`?

And if I want to find the mapped value for a given key, can I use either of the following:

```
mappedVal = map1.at(2);
mappedVal = map1[2];
```

Again, any difference between using `std::unordered_map::at` or `operator[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> map1[2]=5;

If an entry with key `2` exists, set that entry's value to `5`.  Otherwise, create a new entry with key `2` and value `5`.

---

> map1.insert({2,5});

If no entry with key `2` exists, create a new entry with key `2` and value `5`.  Otherwise, **do nothing**.

---

> mappedVal = map1.at(2);

If an entry with key `2` exists, assign its value to `mappedVal`.  Otherwise, throw an `out_of_range` exception.

---

> mappedVal = map1[2];

If an entry with key `2` exists, assign its value to mappedVal.  Otherwise, create an entry for `2` using the default value and assign that default value to mappedVal.

---

For lookups, I usually use `unordered_map::find()` rather than `at()` or `operator [] ()` (unless I know that there is an entry for the given key).

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to `operator[]`, `at()` will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if the key doesn't exist. `operator[]` will create the key instead.

Comment: Thanks. So I take this to mean that if I want to find the value at what I "think" is an existing key, then it would be safer to use `at()`?